# Submitting a form with AJAX causes page reload but only on mobile

Tags: forms, javascript, ajax

I am submitting the user profile edit form by hooking the user profile edit form like this:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
'callback' => 'user_profile_submit',
'wrapper' => $form['#attributes']['id'],
'method' => 'invoke',
'effect' => 'fade',
);
```

The callback function `user_profile_submit` invokes a simple jQuery alert notification specifying if the form was saved successfully. The setup works perfectly on the desktop i.e. the form is submitted with AJAX with no page reload whatsoever. However, saving the same form using mobile devices causes always a page reload. Any idea what might be causing this behavior? Thanks.

**Update:**

Problem can be observed in Chrome/Dolphin but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

I have just downloaded the latest development version of jQuery Update module and the problem was solved. It has to do with this module nothing else.

Comment: When you say "latest development version", do you mean the version committed on 2015-Oct-21, or did you use a specific dev release that's later than that? Because the 2015-Oct-21 version is very likely the same as the prod version of the same date.

Comment: Nope, it is not the same. I mean `7.x-3.x-dev`. If you look closer you see that there is ~ 300kb of extra compressed code in the dev version but not in the release. They can have the same date stamp but the content is different.